# I want the PDF with its first page as the image without the scrollbar

Tags: html, iframe

Here, my code works fine in IE10 but the scroll bar appears in chrome as well as the firefox.
it navigates to the link only when it is clicked by the border of the iframe. Moreover, the iframe is not clickable. Help me out....

```
    <style>
.icon-remove-sign {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
</style>


$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('i.icon-remove-sign').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    pdfID = $(this).closest('.imagewrap')[0].id;
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
  alert('Deleting '+pdfID+'');
   $(this).closest('.imagewrap')
        .fadeTo(300,0,function(){
            $(this)
                .animate({width:0},200,function(){
                    $(this)
                        .remove();
                });
        });   
});
});



<div class="imagewrap">
    <iframe src="http://team358.org/files/website/Basic_HTML_Tutorial.pdf#scrollbar=0&scrolling=0" width="150" height="100" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <a href="http://team358.org/files/website/Basic_HTML_Tutorial.pdf">&nbsp;</a><i class=" icon-remove-sign"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Try with `100%` instead of `100` for width and height.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work, in chrome and firefox the _scrollbar_ appears on the right side.

Comment: U want no scrollbar and if i'm correct u want when people click on the "pdf" they get redirected to the PDF itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    .iframe_thumb {
        position : relative;
        overflow : hidden;
    }
    .iframe_thumb a {
        position : absolute;
        top : 0;
        left : 0;
        width : 100%;
        height : 100%;
        z-index : 10;
    }
    .iframe_thumb .delete {
           postion : absolute;
           top : 5px;
           right: 0;
           z-index : 11;
    }
</style>

<div class="iframe_thumb">
    <iframe src="http://team358.org/files/website/Basic_HTML_Tutorial.pdf#scrollbar=0&scrolling=0" width="100" height="100" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <a href="http://team358.org/files/website/Basic_HTML_Tutorial.pdf">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="url/to/delete" class="delete"><img src="images/delete.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: the PDF has been made clickable inside...thanks for that. but, the scroll bar on the right side still appears. please help me out to remove that.

Comment: this is fine and it is clickable all over the iframe, but I have an icon button to delete the PDF as well. When this code is used along with the delete icon, it fails to work. Help me out with the issue!

Comment: The scrollbar is from the PDF component i'm afraid.
See edit for the delete button

Comment: I think instead of getting the id of imageWrapper, which is not set, try to get the src from the iframe. Then make an ajax call to a script which deletes the PDF

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbar belongs to the PDF plugin, not to the `<iframe>`. So, as far as I know, you cannot control its appearance using HTML or CSS. That is also why the link only works when you click on the border : the border still belongs to the HTML page, but the PDF plugin doesn't delegate the clicks it receives back to the browser (I can't imagine how it could!)

Also, putting an `<iframe>` inside an `<a>` tag ? I've never seen that before and I'm not sure why you would want to do this.

Maybe you want to set your iframe to be the target of your link, like this ?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" name="pdf_frame"></iframe>
<a href="http://team358.org/files/website/Basic_HTML_Tutorial.pdf"
  target="pdf_frame">HTML Tutorial</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p75wM/2/

EDIT : now that I understood your question, I think you'll find [good information here](http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/how-to-create-pdf-preview-images-in-php/) : (also check out [the update to that post](http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/webvamp/how-to-create-pdf-preview-images-in-php-part-2/))

Comment: this has been edit: _http://jsfiddle.net/p75wM/5/_ Please check this out. You will find a scroll bar on the right side which is not actually needed. Help me out.....

Comment: Oh thanks for the information u gave...what I was really trying to do is, I wanted the first page of the PDF as a clickable image. Ok thanks.....

Comment: Ah, ok, I edited my answer with more information. I hope you can solve your problem with this.

Answer (score -1):

Use a container div with style

```
<style>
    #container{width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;}
          iframe{width: 518px; height: 318px;}
    </style>
    <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="container">
    <a href="http://team358.org/files/website/Basic_HTML_Tutorial.pdf">
          <iframe src="http://team358.org/files/website/Basic_HTML_Tutorial.pdf" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" > 

    </iframe></a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Used container div styled with overflow: hidden; to hide the scrollbar. Set the width and the height of the div, to be slightly less than that of your iframe.